# what does make[1]:entering a/b.c.edu/e/r/t/d...

Tags: c, linux

I have seen something like in a lab for writing Unix shell in C.

> make[1]: Entering directory `/a/cs.amu.edu/p/i/i/labs/lab/src'
>   ./driver.pl -t t1.txt -s ./tsh -a "p"

1) what does it mean?

I have a homework that lists it. 
I simply typed

> make

and

> ./driver.pl -t t1.txt -s ./tsh -a "p"

and things worked for me, but when i typed

> make[1]: Entering directory `/a/cs.amu.edu/p/i/i/labs/lab/src'
>   ./driver.pl -t t1.txt -s ./tsh -a "p"

into linux terminal it gave something like this:

> loop$

what is the difference between make and make[1]:....?

2) Also hw asks me to submit by this command:

> cp tsh.c $(HANDINDIR)/$(TEAM)-$(VERSION)-tsh.c

where HANDINDIR gives a path, similar to /a/cs.amu.edu/p/i/i/labs/handin.

If i simply type this command will i be able to handin the work?

Any help is appreciated

Comment: Search for `make[1]: Entering directory '...'`

Answer (score 3):

```
make[1]: Entering directory `/a/cs.amu.edu/p/i/i/labs/lab/src'
./driver.pl -t t1.txt -s ./tsh -a "p"
```

The first line isn't a command. It's just an informational message that `make` is changing its current directory. Also, Makefiles can call other Makefiles, and the `[1]` indicates how many levels deep that is - again, that's just informational.

To get the same effect from a prompt, you would need to type:

```
cd /a/cs.amu.edu/p/i/i/labs/lab/src
./driver.pl -t t1.txt -s ./tsh -a "p"
```